# DIR Functions returning false after a few days

Tags: c++

I have a daemon (running on Ubuntu Server 16.04, compiled with `g++ -std=c++11`) that relies on two functions to know if a directory exists and if it's empty:

```
bool DirectoryExists ( const char* path ) {
    if( path == NULL ) return false;
    DIR *d;
    d = opendir(path);
    if (d){
        closedir(d);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool isEmpty(const char* path) {
    int n = 0;
    //Directory scan
    DIR           *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(path);
    if (d){
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
            if(dir->d_name[0] == '.')continue;
            if(++n > 0) break;
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } 
    if (n == 0) //Directory Empty
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The problem is that after a day or two of the daemon working, these functions start constantly returning `FALSE` (both of them) when they should return `TRUE`. I have the suspicion that the `DIR *` pointer is not closing correctly but I couldn't manage to fix it.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

In some parts of my code, I use `DirectoryExists` to check if a removed directory is actually gone, or if it's still there.  When that checking is done, the `errno` is set to "No such file or directory", which is correct, but I don't know if that could be the source of my problem.

```
system("rm -rf " + fullpath);
if(DirectoryExists(std::string(fullpath).c_str())){
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "ERROR: Directory %s couldn't be removed", fullpath.c_str());
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

As I suspected, when these functions starts failing the errno is set to "too many open files"

Comment: Are you sure these are the functions with the problem?  They look pretty water-tight, but potentially, when something goes wrong elsewhere, it's highlighted by this function first.  How about reading errno to see what the actual error is.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html for example code

Comment: Not sure why is this labeled c++11. There is not a single c++11 feature used in the code posted. In fact, this code is pure C.

Comment: These are the only functions in the whole code who use opendir(), i will add errno to syslog output but it will take it two days to make useful output.

Comment: When a function as simple as that starts going mad after 2 days, I usually suspect a problem such as UB or memory leak in other parts of the code... But I know this is not an answer because I can give no hint on how to be sure of it.

Comment: I don't think that I have a memory leak, I only use malloc once and I free it immediately after use.

Comment: `std::string(fullpath).c_str()` -- Why?! I think it could also be the source of your problems. The temporary is destroyed before the `DirectoryExists` function even enters.

Comment: True,  I don't recall doing that, I'll check it out

Comment: Dangling reference aside, why would you think of using `std::string(fullpath).c_str()` in the first place, when you already use the proper `fullpath.c_str()` on the very next line?

Comment: I'm almost sure I was concatenating something that I later replaced with fullpath

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the offending line is the one containing `std::string(fullpath).c_str()`:

```
if(DirectoryExists(std::string(fullpath).c_str())) {
   ...
}
```

You are using a temporary which gets destroyed before the function even enters. By luck, the memory pointed to by `c_str()` seems to contain the string you want, but at some point this ceases to be the case (perhaps because of memory fragmentation increasing pressure on the memory allocator to reuse memory).

Comment: I will fix that then and post results